# How does bind variable substitution work for page Items in ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-19.1

I was wondering how does ORACLE APEX identify if a certain page item value should go as number or varchar2 when used in stored procedure call.

```
my_pkg.proc1(P1 =>:P2_ITEM1);
```

Here, how does APEX engine identify if the parameter P1 for proc1 is expecting a number or varchar2 or date.

To extend:

I have a grid. With query as below

```
Select * from table(my_pkg.pipe_func(:P2_PARAM1,:P2_PARAM2));
```

When user clicks a button I need to get the current session state value of these bind substitutions and I want to store above select query in a table as

```
Select * from table(my_pkg.pipe_func('ParamVal',256));
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

It's the Oracle database that does this grunt work, in the same way it's done it for years. [You can see this](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2012/02/apex-variables-in-sql.html) in the `v$sqlarea`.

And you should explicity convert these bind variables, as they will be inheretly treated as a varchar - same as they're stored.

```
where id = to_number(:p1_id)
```

And from an APEX perspective, if the user changes a value on screen, and you invoke a dynamic action to refresh a region using those items - you should list them in the 'Page items to submit' attribute, just under the region SQL. This will ensure the database session state is updated with what's in the browser, *before* conducting the refresh.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for your reply. But when we call procedures in APEX, we don't mention to_number We just call my_pkg.proc1(P1 => :P2_ITEM); And this always works irrespective of whether p1 is expecting number, or varchar2. So my question is.. how does APEX do that?